# drupal module statistics not counting recent page views

Tags: drupal, view, statistics, visitors

I have the the statistics module for drupal, but it seems to fail, it doesn't count the page views..
all remains in 0 if I want to show for example a total view for an article in a view, 
and when I enter to admin and try to see the recent visits, it sais that there are no statistics
So it is obviously failing.
I did enable it with the proper permissions...
any iddeas?

Answer (score 1):

It's dumb, but there is a settings page under the report hierarchy of the navigation menu. You must enable a few options in there for statistics to start tracking. In Drupal 7, it's `admin/config/system/statistics`.

Also make sure sure you're only tracking node views or it will fill you watchdog table up so fast you could cry.